# What does Yarn (really) mean by "warning Pattern ["debug@^4.1.1"] is trying to unpack in the same destination"

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, yarnpkg

I see there are other questions regarding this warning from Yarn on Stack Overflow, but I can't find the answer to what it means -- I mean, what it *really* means.  That is, what does it mean for me and my app, and how can I correct it?

I'm trying to add [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) with Yarn, i.e. `yarn add debug -D` and I get the warning

```
warning Pattern ["debug@^4.1.1"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/Users/xyz/Library/Caches/Yarn/v4/npm-debug-4.1.1-3b72260255109c6b589cee050f1d516139664791/node_modules/debug" as pattern ["debug@^4.1.0","debug@^4.0.1"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
```

I tried `yarn remove debug` followed by `yarn add debug -D`, but that didn't work.

Any insights and advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the installer usually creates the directory to install in, but in this case, it stumbled on a situation where the directory already exists.  It is warning you that if it puts the files there, then the new files could co-exist with the files that were already there.

Try running:

```
rm -fR /Users/xyz/Library/Caches/Yarn/v4/npm-debug-4.1.1-3b72260255109c6b589cee050f1d516139664791/node_modules/debug
```

Then try installing again.

If that doesn't work, try running:

```
rm -fR /Users/xyz/Library/Caches/Yarn/v4/npm-debug-4.1.1-3b72260255109c6b589cee050f1d516139664791/node_modules
```

Then try installing again.

Comment: This isn't a caching error in my case. `yarn cache clean` didn't fix anything and the actual lock file refers to two different versions, so the conflict makes sense. That's how Yarn is generating the lock file though, I have no control over the contents of it.